# Error mounting volumes on Openshift (Next gen)

Tags: mongodb, docker, openshift, kubernetes, docker-volume

I'm testing the new Openshift platform based on Docker and Kubernetes.

I've created a new project from scratch, then when I try to deploy a simple MongoDB service (as well with a python app), I got the following errors in the Monitoring section in Web console:

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "mongodb-1-sfg8t_rob1(e9e53040-ab59-11e6-a64c-0e3d364e19a5)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "mongodb-1-sfg8t"/"rob1". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[mongodb-data]
Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "mongodb-1-sfg8t"/"rob1". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[mongodb-data]
```

It seems a problem mounting the PVC in the container, however the PVC is correctly created and bounded:

```
oc get pvc
```

Returns:

```
NAME           STATUS    VOLUME         CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
mongodb-data   Bound     pv-aws-9dged   1Gi        RWO           29m
```

I've deployed it with the following commands:

```
oc process -f openshift/templates/mongodb.json | oc create -f -

oc deploy mongodb --latest
```

The complete log from Web console:

[image]

The content of the template that I used is:

```
{
    "kind": "Template",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "mongo-example",
        "annotations": {
            "openshift.io/display-name": "Mongo example",
            "tags": "quickstart,mongo"
        }
    },
    "labels": {
        "template": "mongo-example"
    },
    "message": "The following service(s) have been created in your project: ${NAME}.",
    "objects": [
        {
            "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${DATABASE_DATA_VOLUME}"
            },
            "spec": {
                "accessModes": [
                    "ReadWriteOnce"
                ],
                "resources": {
                    "requests": {
                        "storage": "${DB_VOLUME_CAPACITY}"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "Service",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}",
                "annotations": {
                    "description": "Exposes the database server"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "name": "mongodb",
                        "port": 27017,
                        "targetPort": 27017
                    }
                ],
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}",
                "annotations": {
                    "description": "Defines how to deploy the database"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "strategy": {
                    "type": "Recreate"
                },
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "type": "ImageChange",
                        "imageChangeParams": {
                            "automatic": true,
                            "containerNames": [
                                "mymongodb"
                            ],
                            "from": {
                                "kind": "ImageStreamTag",
                                "namespace": "",
                                "name": "mongo:latest"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ConfigChange"
                    }
                ],
                "replicas": 1,
                "selector": {
                    "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}",
                        "labels": {
                            "name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "volumes": [
                            {
                                "name": "${DATABASE_DATA_VOLUME}",
                                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                                    "claimName": "${DATABASE_DATA_VOLUME}"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "name": "mymongodb",
                                "image": "mongo:latest",
                                "ports": [
                                    {
                                        "containerPort": 27017
                                    }
                                ],
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "MONGODB_USER",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_USER}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MONGODB_PASSWORD",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "MONGODB_DATABASE",
                                        "value": "${DATABASE_NAME}"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "volumeMounts": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "${DATABASE_DATA_VOLUME}",
                                        "mountPath": "/data/db"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "readinessProbe": {
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 1,
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 5,
                                    "exec": {
                                        "command": [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "mongo --eval 'db.getName()'"]
                                    }
                                },
                                "livenessProbe": {
                                    "timeoutSeconds": 1,
                                    "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
                                    "tcpSocket": {
                                        "port": 27017
                                    }
                                },
                                "resources": {
                                    "limits": {
                                        "memory": "${MEMORY_MONGODB_LIMIT}"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "NAME",
            "displayName": "Name",
            "description": "The name",
            "required": true,
            "value": "mongo-example"
        },    
        {
            "name": "MEMORY_MONGODB_LIMIT",
            "displayName": "Memory Limit (MONGODB)",
            "required": true,
            "description": "Maximum amount of memory the MONGODB container can use.",
            "value": "512Mi"
        },
        {
            "name": "DB_VOLUME_CAPACITY",
            "displayName": "Volume Capacity",
            "description": "Volume space available for data, e.g. 512Mi, 2Gi",
            "value": "512Mi",
            "required": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_DATA_VOLUME",
            "displayName": "Volumne name for DB data",
            "required": true,
            "value": "mongodb-data"
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME",
            "displayName": "Database Service Name",
            "required": true,
            "value": "mongodb"
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_NAME",
            "displayName": "Database Name",
            "required": true,
            "value": "test1"
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_USER",
            "displayName": "Database Username",
            "required": false    
        },
        {
            "name": "DATABASE_PASSWORD",
            "displayName": "Database User Password",
            "required": false    
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any issue with my template ? Is it a OpenShift issue ? Where and how can I get further details about the mount problem in OpenShift logs ?

Comment: For an operational issue like this, it is best to file a bug report via the Bugzilla issue tracker mentioned in the support page for the OpenShift developer preview platform. https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/devpreview_faq.html#devpreview-faq-support

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you're coming up against 2 different issues.

1. You're template is setup to pull from the Mongo image on Dockerhub (specified by the blank "namespace" value. When trying to pull the mongo:latest image from Dockerhub in the Web UI, you are greeted by a friendly message notifying you that the docker image is not usable because it runs as root:
   [image: OpenShift error]
2. OpenShift Online Dev preview *has* been having some issues related to PVC recently (http://status.preview.openshift.com/). Specifically this reported bug at the moment, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1392650. This may be a cause for some issues, as the "official" Mongo image on OpenShift is also failing to build.

---

I would like to direct you to an OpenShift MongoDB template, not the exact one used in the Developer Preview, but should hopefully provide some good direction going forward! https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/roles/openshift_examples/files/examples/v1.4/db-templates/mongodb-persistent-template.json

Comment: Hi, I've tried with the openshift mongo image with the same result, even with your proposed template, but the mount issue still happens. Maybe It's related with the platform issues related with PVCs.

Comment: Yes, sorry...like I said, you were hitting both issues. Had there not been a PVC issue, the Dockerhub image would have still failed because OpenShift Online does not allow images to run as root....but as you saw, even the "official" image fails. Please feel free to subscribe to the Bugzilla bug to follow the resolution of this issue!

Comment: OK, I'll wait for the resolution of the issue #1392650 that you pointed me, the same error msg is described there. However I'm not sure that the original mongo image is wrong, because the default mongod service runs with user mongodb, anyway, I'll try again when the issue is fixed to confirm it. Thanks for your help.